# WPF Grid : GridSplitter event

Tags: c#, wpf, wpf-controls, gridsplitter

I need to put a event while resizing grid columns using a gridsplitter.
I tried using 'sizeChanged' event on the columns getting affected. But its not working
Please tell me how to do that
Thanks

Comment: Duplicate here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6711162/how-to-handle-events-generated-by-grid-splitter-in-wpf/22495586#22495586

Answer (score 2):

I use the SizeChanged event on content within the columns.

```
<Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="leftColumn" MinWidth="268" Width="268*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="centerColumn" MinWidth="327" Width="327*"/>
        <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
        <ColumnDefinition x:Name="rightColumn" MinWidth="393" Width="393*"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
    <custom:Control x:Name="panel1" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,0,5" SizeChanged="PanelSizeChanged"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="1" Background="#00000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
    <custom:Control x:Name="panel2" Grid.Column="2" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,0,5" SizeChanged="PanelSizeChanged"/>
    <GridSplitter Grid.Column="3" Background="#00000000" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" ResizeBehavior="PreviousAndNext" Width="5" ResizeDirection="Columns"/>
    <custom:Control x:Name="panel2" Grid.Column="4" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" Margin="5,0,0,5" SizeChanged="PanelSizeChanged"/>
</Grid>
```

I manage all of the size change stuff I need in the one callback PanelSizeChanged. You could of course use different handlers for each column.