# How to handle events generated by Grid Splitter in WPF?

Tags: wpf

I want an event handler that handles the event when the grid splitter is being moved, Im not sure if there is one, if not, I guess I can generated an event when the size of the rows are changed?

Thanks.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You could do the rows changing size, but GridSplitter itself is a Thumb and so has its own events such as DragStarted and DragCompleted.  More details [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.gridsplitter_events.aspx).

**Edit:** If you make the GridSplitter focusable and allow it to be moved with the keyboard, read the answer by Benlitz for more information.

Comment: Read it even if you don't worry about the keyboard, because it is a common design error to handle the wrong event (one of the input action, instead of the general result of the action)

Comment: Then elaborate :) I'm curious why you'd favor a non-extensible method based on a single type of user action, over handling the adequate property change, while both have about the same cost of implementation. Suppose after implementing this, you're asked to add a button that restore the default row size. Changing the size programmatically wouldn't be handled. This is why I believe this approach is not good ; it can easily introduce vicious bugs in your UI. If the operation you do in the handler of the row size change is not clearly visible, you might not even notice the problem for weeks.

Comment: As an example, reacting to a thumb DragDelta rather than a resize has a much different animation effect -- check with Snoop and watch the differet messages and how granular they are.  Finally, as long as the keyboard can't be used to resize the GridSplitter (focusable = false), it's a moot point anyway.

Answer (score 9):

I didn't tested, but I'm pretty sure that the currently accepted answer from AresAvatar won't work if you're resizing the rows/columns using keyboard arrows (by giving the focus to the grid splitter). This is a rare but possible case that you should anticipate in your application.

When the grid splitter is moved (either by drag'n'drop or using keyboard arrows), it changes the `Width`/`Height` dependency properties of the `ColumnDefinitions`/`RowDefinitions` of the grid. You can easily register a handler on this property change:

```
var heightDescriptor = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(RowDefinition.HeightProperty, typeof(ItemsControl));
heightDescriptor.AddValueChanged(myGrid.RowDefinitions[0], HeightChanged);
```

(This snippet will for instance track size change in the first row of the grid).

Then you can handle resize in an handler that will work in every case.

```
private void HeightChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    // TODO: handle row resize
}
```

Generally, it is really not advised to rely on the user input action (mouse dragging, keyboard inputs...) to handle a logical or visual actions/events, since there are almost always several ways to do the same actions using different inputs (mouse, keyboards, touchscreen, ease-of-use tools...).

Comment: Hi @Benlitz, this answer doesn't make a lot of sense.  If you allow the GridSplitter to get keyboard focus, it works as it is supposed to.

Comment: It makes perfect sense. If you want to handle the event "The grid splitter is moved" (OP question), you should NOT handle DragStarted/Completed, because it would assume that dragging the mouse is the only way to move the splitter, which is wrong. The approach itself is wrong, because you handle one of the possible cause (dragging), instead of handling the consequence (splitter has moved). The illustration I gave to prove my point is that moving the splitter using keyboard arrows won't fire drag events (I tested it right now).

Comment: OK, I understand your answer better now with your comment.  If you make the GridSplitter focusable, and allow keyboard movement, it does not generate drag events.  I've added a note to my answer to read yours.

Comment: Note that the GridSplitter is focusable by default (with the generic/Aero themes at least)

Comment: No, it is not focusable by default.  I tested that specifically.

Comment: Me too. Clicking on a gridsplitter allowed me to move it using keyboard (without explicitly setting Focusable=true). And WPFInspector explicitly showed me that this property is true. But different OS/version of .NET might change the default value (I'm on win7/.NET 4.5)

Comment: Odd.  I am using Win7 and .NET 4.5.1.  Perhaps there's something else going on with yours (inheritance?).  In any event I'm giving you an upvote for pointing this out.

Answer (score 0):

Use DragDelta. Be aware that if you want to change the size, use as the Actual property as the current size like ActualWidth instead of Width.